# GNS3 switches vs Real switches performance

Tags: switch, network, switching, networking, gns3

I want to emulate the performance of switches in GNS3, and the focus is not the configuration of switches. My questions are:

1. Do emulated switches perform worst than actual switches?
2. Are emulated switches are good method to measure the throughput performance of a network?
3. Is GNS3 a good choice to do such measurements or any alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Do emulated switches perform worst than actual switches?

Yes, of course software performs worse than hardware. Physical switches do their switching in hardware, and are able the get wirespeed switching, but software switches are much slower.

> 2. Are emulated switches are good method to measure the throughput
>    performance of a network?

No, not even close.

> 3. Is GNS3 a good choice to do such measurements or any alternatives?

No it is not a good choice for network measurements (possible to compare different GNS3 topologies, but not against the real world). Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic, except on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). You will not find any software switches that compare with physical hardware switches in speed.